# How to save a nested json in txt file with php

Tags: php, json, coding-style, nested

How can I quick and easy save a JSON nested with php. What I mean with nested is this:

**nested json:**

```
{
    "key1":"value",
    "key2":"value",
    "key3":"value",
    "key4":{
        "key1":"value",
        "key2":"value",
        "key3":"value"
    },
    "key5":{
        "key1":"value",
        "key2":"value",
        "key3":"value"
    }
}
```

**json plain in one line**(When I just use echo json_encode($array))**:**

```
{"key1":"value","key2":"value","key3":"value","key4":{"key1":"value","key2":"value","key3":"value"},"key5":{"key1":"value","key2":"value","key3":"value"}}
```

The reason I want this is that the json must be easy readable for humans. When everything is smacked on one line that doesn't help.

Comment: What is the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the right `$options` parameter for [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) (PHP >= 5.4)

```
echo json_encode($object, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Oh gosh I use PHP 5.3.9 and JSON_PRETTY_PRINT is added in version 5.4.0